# [JDBI][Java] JDBI .bind function doesn't work in this query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbi

terribly sorry if this seems inadequately researched or poorly attempted. I'm a beginner and I've been at this for some hours now trying different variants of :value, (:value), ?, (?), bindBean, bind, etc to no avail. I am at my wits end.

I have a table with 4 columns that I'd like to return the contents of per query (will only return one row) as objects.

The query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    schema.relation
WHERE
    entity = :value
```

That's the query. Here's the function (for claritys sake, I used an 8 digit number for testing myself, say 12345678):

```
    public DatabaseEntry GetInfo(long value) {
        jdbi.registerRowMapper(DatabaseEntry.class,
                (rs, ctx) -> new DatabaseEntry(
                        rs.getString(1),
                        rs.getString(2),
                        rs.getString(3),
                        rs.getString(4)));

        return Try.of(
                () -> jdbi.withHandle((HandleCallback<DatabaseEntry, SQLException>) handle ->
                        handle.select(Queries.DatabaseDetails())
                                .bind("value", value)
                                .map(new DatabaseEntryMapper())
                                .findOnly()
                )
        ).getOrElseThrow((Function<Throwable, RuntimeException>) RuntimeException::new);
    }
```

And the mapper class:

```
public class DatabaseEntryMapper implements RowMapper<DatabaseEntry> {

    @Override
    public DatabaseEntry map(ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {

        final String valueone = rs.getString(1);
        final String valuetwo = rs.getString(2);
        final String valuethree = rs.getString(3);
        final String valuefour = rs.getString(4);

        return new DatabaseEntry(valueone, valuetwo, valuethree, valuefour);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is it seems to not bind the argument value to :value in the query. Which means the db (oracle) translates it to "?". I can't find a way to bind the argument value from just reading the available doc (I don't understand it fully, and haven't found examples showcasing this either). Any explanation of where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated.

This is the errormessage: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No element found in 'only'

Here's the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>SomeArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- logger -->
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- lib for SQL -->
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi3-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- lib for connection pool / data source for SQL -->
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- lib for functional java programming -->
            <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- lib for unit testing -->
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- lib for microweb-development -->
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-template-velocity</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: what is error you're getting ?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No element found in 'only'

I interpret this as the variable not being bound.

Comment: Looks like your result set is empty. See here. line no 99 https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jdbi/v3/core/result/ResultIterable.java

Comment: That is correct; the resultset returned by this code is empty because it queries "?" instead of the actual value passed to it via the argument in my function (long value).

Comment: Jdbi changes your variable to '?' and pass parameters to replace. If you could log your queries with parameter that would help to debug

Comment: Good point, thanks. I used an 8 digit value.